# ui-bootstrap pagination with filter

Tags: angularjs

after some research and study of examples I implemented a pagniation with a filter function.

Im very new to angular, so I need your help if this application is ok or it has some bugs/logical errors.

The target is to select a collection (in this application load1 or load2) and create new objects, manipulate existing, or delete some of them. On every update of the data, it has to be checked if the pagination is synchronous to the collection size.
If the user enters something into the search field, a watcher in the controller is fired for updating the filtered data:

```
$scope.$watch('search.name', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.items, {name: newVal});
}, true);
```

I would be very happy if some of you angular pros can look into this code and give me some feedback. I want to use this in a productive system, so every answer would be great!

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/j9DVahEm7y1j5MfsRk1F?p=preview

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watchers are heavy if you use them explicitly throughout your large application.
Use `ng-change` instead. Also, by passing `true` to that watcher means you're deep watching which is really a bad thing to do, since it will check each property of the object in the array which is performance intensive.

Since I can't see that you need old and new value for a reason, you can simply use `$scope.search.name`. Whenever you type in something, `$scope.search.name` has the updated value. Just need to call a function on `ng-change`.

**DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/TWjEoM3oPdfrHfcru7LH?p=preview**

Remove watch and use:

```
$scope.updateSearch = function () {
    $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.items, {name: $scope.search.name});
};
```

In HTML:

```
<label>Search:</label> <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Search" ng-change="updateSearch()" />
```

Comment: BTW, nice attempt at implementing a good pagination and search functionality. I like it!

Comment: I'm glad to hear this. But this solution is based on some examples I found in the internet ;-). But thanks again for your very fast help! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is still the correct, but you will have to make sure to replace the "page" inside the pagination tag and change it to ng-model.

From the changelog (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Since 0.11.0:

Both pagination and pager are now integrated with ngModelController.

- page is replaced from ng-model.